# Encoding database sql in qml

Tags: utf-8, qml, qstring

I'm reading Data from a `.mdb Database`. Viewing it with `MS Access`, it shows special chars normal. `"äöü"` ...

Loading the data in `qml (using c++ / QDatabase)` I get all special chars shown like : `"?" (even in qDebug << ...)`

I googled a lot, seems it is a encoding problem with `utf-8 / utf-16.`
I know `QStrings` are stored as `utf-16`, but that doesn't help me fixing my problem.

I tried to make the database `utf-8` but it seemed not to work
But I just cant get it to work.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem?